# Ocultar o mostrar al hacer scroll

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, recyclerview, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy intentando hacer una animación simple: Cuando se scrollee hacia abajo en un RecyclerView que se oculte la barra superior, y cuando se scrollee hacia arriba y se llegue al item #1 que se vuelva a mostrar. Lo hago de esta forma:

```
RecyclerView vRecyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.RecyclerNewsFeedI);
vRecyclerView.ScrollChange += delegate
            {                
                OcultarMostrarSuperiores();
            };
```

Ocupo una variable global publica llamada `VarGlobal.gFlagoScroll1` que toma el Id del `position` en el `OnBindViewHolder()` para que me diga cuando la (`position` > 2) y (`position` < 2).

```
OcultarMostrarSuperiores()
{
            if (VarGlobal.gFlagoScroll1 >= 2)
            {
                vxLinearLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayoutTNF);
                vxLinearLayout.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Gone;

                vxLinearLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.LayoutNFB);
                vxLinearLayout.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Gone;
            }
            else
            {
                vxLinearLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayoutTNF);
                vxLinearLayout.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Visible;

                vxLinearLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.LayoutNFB);
                vxLinearLayout.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Visible;
            }
}
```

Funciona bien cuando scrolleo hacia abajo, el problema es que cuando quiero scrollear hacia arriba funciona solo cuando estoy muy abajo, (como por el item 8) debido a que de lo contrario aun no se ha reciclado el CardView del item 2 y no gatilla el OnBindViewHolder el item 2 por lo que no se me actualiza la variable VarGlobal.gFlagoScroll1.

Alguna idea de como lograrlo de una manera mas fiable?

Comment: El recycler tiene un scroll listener creo , ahi extrae el layoutmanager y pregunta que vista esta de primero y obten el index eon este layout manager, si es el 0  muestra tu barra. El layout manager tiene funciones para esa informacion de visibilidad.

Comment: Muchas gracias, gracias a tu referencia encontre la solucion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo.

Queda de la siguiente forma:

```
vRecyclerView.ScrollChange += delegate
            {                
                OcultarMostrarSuperiores();
            };

OcultarMostrarSuperiores()
{

    int PrimerElementoActualVisible = linearLayoutManager.FindFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    
                if (PrimerElementoActualVisible > 0) //Condicion opcional
                {
                    vxLinearLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayoutTNF);
                    vxLinearLayout.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Gone;
    
                    vxLinearLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.LayoutNFB);
                    vxLinearLayout.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Gone;
                }
                else
                {
                    vxLinearLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayoutTNF);
                    vxLinearLayout.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Visible;
    
                    vxLinearLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.LayoutNFB);
                    vxLinearLayout.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Visible;
                }
}
```